# Ignore Where Clause In View

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Consider a table and a view of the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE t (a VARCHAR(10), b VARCHAR(10), c VARCHAR(10))
```

I have a query that runs against the table with two where clauses.

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE b = "foo" AND c="bar"
```

I'd like to create the view so that the same query can be used but ignores one of the two where clauses.

Is this possible (I suspect not)?

Like

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT a, b, [whatever is asked for in the query] AS c FROM t;
```

(Reason for this is can't modify the query without much more effort than creating a new view.)

Comment: "Two WHERE clauses" = `WHERE ... AND ...`?

Comment: It would have been nice if you have posted the real table and queries to understand the question better.

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul See my edit PK could be column A, but shouldn't be relevant.  Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I think you gave the only solution yourself: If you know what is asked for in the WHERE clause you could make a view where that condition is always true. Unfortunately I can't think of anything that is always equal if compared to anything.

Comment: What's given in the WHERE clause is variable, so I don't know it ahead of time.  I think because the view is set up before the query is run, this is impossible.  Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Since a database view can be used only to define the projection and the criteria to retrieve the projection from one or more tables, you cannot include conditional logic to select only certain portion of the project or only certain filters, in the view definition. These can be specified only on top of the view definition like

```
SELECT <subset of projection> from <VIEW>
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM <VIEW> WHERE <more filters>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave the only solution yourself. If you know what is asked for in the WHERE clause you could make a view where that condition is always true:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT a, b, "bar" AS c FROM t;
```

If the values for `c` are limited you could get away with something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT a, b, "bar" AS c FROM t;
UNION
SELECT a, b, "bar1" AS c FROM t;
UNION
SELECT a, b, "barsomething" AS c FROM t;
```